# Extract Average time from output of ping command in python

Tags: python, average, ping

How can I extract Average time from output of ping command in python.  Here is the output of the ping :

```
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 31.907/37.303/51.442/8.194 ms
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well if the output is the same every time you could do a few things. You could remove the first bit of information "rtt min/avg/max/mdev = " by doing the following.

```
>>> yourString[23:]
```

where 23 is the number of characters you want to cut off the front.

Then do the same for the ms on the end

```
>>> yourString[:-3]
```

Where 3 is the number you want to remove.

Then finally you can run an explode on the object to get the average value, splitting by the "/"

```
>>>youString.split('/')
```

Then you can just grab the second value in yourString and you will have your average.

Answer (score 0):

Calvin's suggestion to use `split` is probably the best for this case. But for the general case, familiarize yourself with regular expressions and the python implementation, the **re** module - https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/re.html. Using them you could write a rule that matches the exact part of the line that you want to extract. I will leave writing the pattern to you as an exercise, but once that is done you can achieve the following:

```
>>> re.findall(pattern, "rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 31.907/37.303/51.442/8.194 ms")
['37.303']
```